# Recordset.EOF and Recordset.next (ADO) equivalent on Express/Pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Good afternoon, I can't find any way to move cross recordset (as I did in ADO).
Below It's an example for what I have done in .pug, with error: "*items is undefined on line 1*"

**server.js**

```
//...
res.render('ItemsList.pug', {
    items: row
    }, function(err, html) {
    res.status(200).send(html)
  });
```

**ItemsList.pug**

```
   - for (var i = 0; items.length; i++) {
        p
        div
            div(id='items' + items[i].rowid)
                div
                    img(src='img/'+ items[i].tapa)
                br/ items[i].titulo 
                br/ items[i].titulo_alt
                img(class='right' src='img/'+ items[i].min +'.gif') 
                br/ 2017
        - i++;
            div(id='items' + items[i].rowid)
                div
                    img(src='img/'+ items[i].tapa)
                br/ items[i].titulo 
                br/ items[i].titulo_alt
                img(class='right' src='img/'+ items[i].min +'.gif') 
                br/ 2017
   -}
```

Comment: Read this and then try, https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html And use `item` instead of `items[i]` also, why are you incrementing `i` within the loop?

Comment: For css issues, I used columns of 2 items. I was able to solve it with columns of 1 item, obtaining the same style result.
However, the problem of `EoF (ADO)`, I solve it with `if (items.length)`.

Answer (score 0):

**ItemsList.pug**

```
- if(items.length)
    - for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++)
        p
        div(class='col4 col8')
            div(class='container' id='p' + items[i].rowid)
                div(class='display-container imageZoom')
                    img(src='img/'+ items[i].front style='width:100%;height: 300px')
                br/ #{items[i].title} 
                br/ #{items[i].title_alt}
- else
    div(class='bar')
        div(class='bar-item') No Products Found
```